# Clicking on java script generated dynamic elements using Remote Web Driver in selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, browser-automation, selenium-webdriver

I have one web page, all the elements on that page are generated by java script code. I want to click on one of the button on that page, I was able to do this using the chrome driver,FF Driver but failed to achieve the same with Remote Web Driver class. If anybody worked around it, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Are you creating object for the `RemoteWebdriver` class and setting the capablities for the firefox browser and chrome browser, on which you want to run the tests?

Ex:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver();
capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
```

Pass the capability object to the driver.

Comment: Hello SaiKrishna, Thanks for your answer . I am getting the following exception  


org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{platform=ANY, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, version=8}]
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'

Comment: Are you sure that chrome version is 8?